# Excel formula for retrieving last portion of a url

Tags: excel, url, formula

I am trying to write a excel forumla that takes the following:

```
http://www.saga.co.uk/money/taxandbenefits/carersallowance.asp
http://www.saga.co.uk/money/taxandbenefits/index.asp
```

and from these 2 examples would output:

```
carersallowance
index
```

Anyone know how this could be done ? Help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If you example was in A1 try

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND("/",A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),""),".asp","")
```

Comment: great thanks will give these a go now.. AND YES WORKING A TREAT. BRILLIANT. Edward

Comment: Thx Edward, glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 4):

Another way;

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("::",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","::",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))))
```

Comment: Alex, that needs a minor mod to remove .asp suffix. :)